# Easiest way to save an S4 class

Tags: r, class, save, r-s4

Probably the most basic question on S4 classes imaginable here.

What is the simplest way to save an S4 class you have defined so that you can reuse it elsewhere. I have a project where I'm taking a number of very large datasets and compiling summary information from them into small S4 objects. Since I'll therefore be switching R sessions to create the summary object for each dataset, it'd be good to be able to load in the definition of the class from a saved object (or have it load automatically) rather than having to include the long definition of the object at the top of each script (which I assume is bad practice anyway because the code defining the object might become inconsistent).

So what's the syntax along the lines of saveclass("myClass"), loadclass("myclass") or am I just thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: The typical way is to make a package and load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setClass("track", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
x <- new("track", x=1:4, y=5:8)
```

## save as binary

```
fn <- tempfile()
save(x, ascii=FALSE, file=fn)
rm(x)
load(fn)
x
```

## save as  ASCII

```
save(x, ascii=TRUE, file=fn)
```

## ASCII text representation from which to regenerate the data

```
dput(x, file=fn)
y <- dget(fn)
```

The [original source](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-read-and-write-an-S4-class-td898607.html) can be found here.

Answer (score 2):

From the question, I think you really *do* want to include the class definition at the top of each script (although not literally; see below), rather than saving a binary representation of the class definition and load that. The reason is the general one that binary representations are more fragile (subject to changes in software *implementation*) compared to simple text representations (for instance, in the not too distant past S4 objects were based on simple lists with a class attribute; more recently they have been built around an S4 'bit' set on the underlying C-level data representation).

Instead of copying and pasting the definition into each script, really the best practice is to included the class definition (and related methods) in an R package, and to load the package at the top of the script. It is not actually hard to write packages; an easy way to get started is to use Rstudio to create a 'New Project' as an 'R package'. Use a version number in the package to keep track of the specific version of the class definition / methods you're using, and version control (svn or git, for instance) to make it easy to track the changes / explorations you make as your class matures. Share with your colleagues and eventually the larger R community to let others benefit from your hard work and insight!